What is the purpose of putting function objects in a copyable-box or movable-box?
In the C++ ranges library function objects, such as the ones stored in transform_view and filter_view, are put in an exposition-only type called a copyable-box (until C++23) or movable-box (since C++23).
What is the purpose of this?  Why is copy/move constructibility insufficient?  I can't come up with any examples where it would be useful to copy/move assign a view to another, especially since almost every view containing a function object is of a different type (as the function objects are usually lambda expressions).
(Note that this question is about why it was originally copyable-box and not movable-box, but my question is about why we might even want any kind of box.)

does this answer not contain the answer also to your question when it says "Historically, when these adaptors were added, views were required to be copyable, so we required the function objects to be copy_constructible (we couldn't require copyable without ruling out captureful lambdas). "

No, that statement simply begets the question of why anyone would want views to be copyable (i.e. both copy constructible and copy assignable).  I can totally see a use for copy constructible views, but not copy assignable views, and that statement doesn't explain it.
